# List of Tuple trouble

Tags: c#, list, collections, tuples, abstraction

edit: solved, sorry about this, was due to a typo.

---

This code.

```
List<Tuple<Int16, Int16>> a = new List<Tuple<Int16, Int16>>();
Tuple<UInt16, UInt16> b = Tuple.Create<UInt16, UInt16>(4, 2);
a.Add(b);
```

Produces the following error for `a.Add(b)`

```
The best overloaded method match for
'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<short,short>>
.Add(System.Tuple<short,short>)'
has some invalid arguments.
```

In short

```
List<Tuple<short,short>>.Add(Tuple<short,short>)
has invalid arguments
```

I can't see how this is.

Comment: @dtb: that is the answer. Either you answer the question, or we close it, because this must be a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add an `UInt16` pair to a list of `Int16` pairs. That doesn't work.

You can add an `Int16` pair to a list of `Int16` pairs:

```
List<Tuple<Int16, Int16>> a = new List<Tuple<Int16, Int16>>();
Tuple<Int16, Int16> b = Tuple.Create<Int16, Int16>(4, 2);
a.Add(b);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Tuple<Int16, Int16>`  and `Tuple<UInt16, UInt16>` are two different type of tuple.

Answer (score 1):

`UInt` is not an `Int`

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you exactly the problem and the solution. Try the short instead of unsigned short